# MDX/SSAS: Create Year-Ago Version

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have the following cube structure:

**Version Dimension**

```
Actuals
Forecast
Budget
```

**Time Dimension**

```
FY15
   Q1
     P1
     P2
     P3
   ...
FY14
   ...
```

**Measures**

```
Value
```

There's been a request to build a report with Actuals, Actuals Last Year, Budget, and Forecast all on the same row, and I'm having a difficult time. Essentially, the business is asking for an "Actuals Last Year" version, and I don't know how to build that using the `ParallelPeriod` function with a created member.

Comment: How is the time dimension applied to the report, other than for Actuals Last Year?

Comment: A user would drag the time dimension on rows while Actuals Last Year would be on columns. The time dimension on rows could be year, quarter, or period.

Comment: drag?   Are you writing MDX, or is this for Excel, or what?

Comment: I'm thinking of the users perspective from Excel, but I need to create a version dimension member in MDX that mimics their requirement.

Comment: So then you will be dynamically building MDX based on user choices?  If so, then why not simply create a calculated member for [Actuals Last Year] that specifies a member of the time dimension instead of messing with functions like ParallelPeriod?

Comment: Please provide your current attempt at the `MDX`